# How to eliminate curly braces in Label (text=)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

How to eliminate curly braces around "There are total" and "entries in dictionary"

[image]

```
self.status_bar = Label(self.status_bar, text=("There are total", len(dictionary_data), "entries in dictionary."), bg="yellow", relief=FLAT)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are currently passing a tuple for the `text` parameter.  Instead, you should be passing a string.  You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert the dictionary length into this string:

```
self.status_bar = Label(self.status_bar, text="There are total {} entries in dictionary.".format(len(dictionary_data)), bg="yellow", relief=FLAT)
```